# Android WebView unable to load URL

Tags: android, webview

can someone please help me with the WebView? I have the URL that can be open in Web Browser. Unfortunately, it cannot be load into the WebView. I try many ways but still could not solve the problem.

Here's my code for WebView

```
private void setupWeb()

{
    String url = "https://lemmamedia.com/app/html5/?pid=139&aid=4007&at=3";

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 10 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 10MB
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );
    webView.loadUrl(url);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap facIcon)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error)
        {
            handler.proceed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {

        }
    });
}
```

Here's my debug console
[image: Here's my debug console]

Comment: Have checked your URL to browser it's showing a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

Replace in your code with below -

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    view.loadUrl(url);
    return false;
}
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: Still cannot load the URL. The WebView is blank

Answer (score 0):

did you already put the internet permission in **AndroidManifest.xml** ?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: can you also post the code you done in Android Manifest

Answer (score 0):

Your url have no data So,it shows blank page into webview try to add another url and check it.

And don't forgot to give **internet permission** in your **Manifest**

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**YourWebViewActivity.java**

```
String url = "https://lemmamedia.com/app/html5/?pid=139&aid=4007&at=3";

// Enable the javascript
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

// Render the web page
mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: @HaziqAbdullah this blank result because of in your url have no data if you open this link in your browser it's also shows blank.